# How calculate confidence score for text recognition in ocr

Tags: python, ocr, multilingual, metrics, levenshtein-distance

Currently I am working on Vietnamse text recognition in image ocr.

I am struggling with evaluation metric has I don't have any ground truth to calculate the levistance distance or to calculate cer(character error rate) and wer(word error rate)

Can some help me with this

My scenario

I have a prediction text of Vietnamese from an image to evaluate or to compare I dont have a ground truth or reference

If not vietnamese language for any language how to evaluate without ground truth or reference (any libraries, method or code that can help me)

Thanks

Comment: You could use ocr flows that leverage machine learning models. These will return confidence scores on the fly. Cf https://pypi.org/project/paddleocr/

Comment: Yeah, I have tried paddleocr and easyocr. Paddleocr didnt got trained on Vietnamese thats why it's not giving good results and easyocr trained on vietnamese but not recognizing good. I am going with vietocr. It is giving good result compared to paddel and easy but vietocr doesnt giving confidence score. Thats why I wanted to calculate the score

Comment: The demo of EasyOCR here seems to offer quite good results  as long as you set `vi` as the language https://www.jaided.ai/easyocr/

Comment: Yes, it's giving good results but if u see some more complicated imgs like crushed or rotated imgs than its not identifying properly and the extracted text is not 100% sequenced which shows in the image. I tried different images as my analyses vietocr is predicting better than easyocr. but the drawback for vietocr is we need to pass cropped images